# Closure in a Hilbertspace

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Define for a self-adjoint pure contraction $S$ (remember: $\|S\|\leq1$ and $\pm1\notin\sigma_p(S))$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ the following set: $C_c^*(S):=\{g(S):g\in C_c(\hat{\sigma}(S))\}$ with $\hat{\sigma}(S)=\sigma(S)\cap(-1,1)$. Now i to prove that $\overline{C^*_c(S)\mathcal{H}}=\mathcal{H}$. Can someone give an example of self-adjoint pure contraction? Does someone can give an example where this is true? Maybe the multiplication operator $m_f$ on $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $f=\overline{f}$?

Thank you for help :)

Comment: Note proper use of \langle and \rangle in $\langle x,g(S)y_0\rangle$ rather than $< x,g(S)y_0>$.  I also attended to a bit of copy-editing that is a less drastic change but occurred a rather large number of times.

Comment: thank you for correcting :) g(S) is defined for example by the continuous functional calculus.

Comment: If you have an element $a\in A$ with $A$ a $C^*$-algebra then one can have look to $C^*(a)$ the $C^*$-algebra generated by the identity and $a\in A$. Then by the Gelfand transform this is isometric isomorphic to $C(\sigma(a))$ the continuous functions on the spectrum of $a$. Thus if we have the element $a\in C^*(a)$ then one can take the image under this isomorphism. This gives the continuous functional calculus. This is when $a$ is normal.

Comment: Otherwise do someone know a pure contraction which is self-adjoint to make the thing easier?

Comment: The easiest example of a pure contraction is the zero operator.  Thank you for clarifying the question.  Where is the problem from?

Comment: The nontrivial case is where $\|S\|=1$.

Comment: Yes i thought so. Can you say what the problem is and is the statement above true?

Comment: @Serre135:  I guess it is true but don't know.  The trivial case is where we could have $g(S)=I$, the identity operator, and we could do that if $\sigma(S)\subset(-1,1)$, which will happen precisely when $\|S\|<1$.  So suppose $\|S\|=1$. Then the spectrum contains $1$ or $-1$.  For each positive integer $n$, let $g_n$ be a continuous function on $[-1,1]$ such that $0\leq g_n(x)\leq 1$ for all $x$, $g_n(x)=1$ when $|x|\leq 1-\frac1n$, and $g_n(x)=0$ when $|x|\geq 1-\frac1{2n}$.  I guess $\bigcup_n g_n(S)H$ is dense in $H$.  (It is just a guess.)

Comment: @Serre135: To make it so that others receive notifications of your comments, write `@username` in your comment.  Otherwise the automatic notifications occur in limited circumstances, such as when it is a comment on your post. (So I don't need to do this to alert you, but I'm showing you what it looks like.)  I only noticed your comments when I happened to check back.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: I will check it if i find a good operator which satisfies the conditions.

Comment: @Serre135: If you mean you want an operator $S$ to test out a nontrivial case of the problem, try multiplication by $x$ on $L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Holds $\pm1\notin\sigma_p(S)$? I try this :)

Comment: @Serre135: Check for yourself that the point spectrum is empty, but the spectrum is [0,1].

Comment: Yes you are right. $\sigma_p(S)=\varnothing$ and $\sigma(S)=\overline{\mathcal{R}(f)}=[0,1]$. Therefore $[0,1]\cap(-1,1)=[0,1)$. Now i will go on.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: How to define the continuous functional calculus of piecewise linear functions. Say if we take the $g_n$ as above then $g_n(S)x=0$ under what conditions and the same for $g_n(S)x=x$, thus how to translate for example $g_n(x)=1$ for $|x|\leq1-\frac{1}{n}$ to $g_n(S)$? Do you say $g_n(S)h=h$ if $|S|\leq Id-\frac{1}{n}Id$?

Comment: Okay one can use Weierstrass.